# Color Status indicator in O365 SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am working with **O365 SharePoint Online** platform with SharePoint lists around 300 items in All Items View.  For the first 30 items **Text to Html** Javascript function successfully converts text code to Html and displays status in HTML color format, but when I am trying to select next 31 items and go ahead using the pagination the function does not able to convert Html and display only text codes. I also changed the calculated column  value type to "Number" to get the HTML to render in the list view. But not being changed yet. Does anyone please who have the code handy to make this work easy?  Below is the Text to HTML code used in O365 platform.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function TextToHTML(NodeSet, HTMLregexp) {
var CellContent = "";
var i=0;
while (i < NodeSet.length){
try {
CellContent = NodeSet[i].innerText || NodeSet[i].textContent;
if (HTMLregexp.test(CellContent)) {NodeSet[i].innerHTML = CellContent;}
} 
catch(err){}
i=i+1;
}
}

// Calendar views
var regexpA = new RegExp("\\s*<([a-zA-Z]*)(.|\\s)*/\\1?>\\s*");
TextToHTML(document.getElementsByTagName("a"),regexpA);

// List views
var regexpTD = new RegExp("^\\s*<([a-zA-Z]*)(.|\\s)*/\\1?>\\s*$");
TextToHTML(document.getElementsByTagName("TD"),regexpTD);

// This function is call continuesly every 100ms until the length of the main field changes
// after which the convert text to HTML is executed.
//
var postElemLength = 0;
function PostConvertToHtml() 
{
     if (postElemLength == document.getElementsByTagName("TD").length)
     {
          setTimeout(PostConvertToHtml,100);
     }
     else
     {
          var regexpTD = new RegExp("^\\s*<([a-zA-Z]*)(.|\\s)*/\\1?>\\s*$");
          TextToHTML(document.getElementsByTagName("TD"),regexpTD);
     }
}

// Grouped list views
ExpGroupRenderData = (function (old) {
    return function (htmlToRender, groupName, isLoaded) {

    var result = old(htmlToRender, groupName, isLoaded);
    var regexpTD = new RegExp("^\\s*<([a-zA-Z]*)(.|\\s)*/\\1?>\\s*$");
    TextToHTML(document.getElementsByTagName("TD"),regexpTD);

    // start the periodic callback to check when the element has been changed
    if(isLoaded == 'false')
        {
        postElemLength = document.getElementsByTagName("TD").length;
        setTimeout(PostConvertToHtml,100);
        }
    };
})(ExpGroupRenderData);

// Preview pane views
if (typeof(showpreview1)=="function") {
showpreview1 = (function (old) {
    return function (o) {
    var result = old(o);
    var regexpTD = new RegExp("^\\s*<([a-zA-Z]*)(.|\\s)*/\\1?>\\s*$");
    TextToHTML(document.getElementsByTagName("TD"),regexpTD);
    };
})(showpreview1);
}</script>
```

Below is the generated text code which needs to be converted to Html used in calculated columns. Thanks.

```
=IF([Trend]="Cancelled","DarkGray",IF([Trend]="Completed","DodgerBlue",IF([Trend]="Declining","DarkOrange",IF([Trend]="Improving","ForestGreen",IF([Trend]="No Change","ForestGreen",IF([Trend]="Not Started","White",IF([Trend]="On Hold","DarkGray","")))))))
```

And..

```
="<div style='position:relative;display:inline-block;width:100%;'>
    <div style='width:100%;display:inline-block;text-align:center;border:1px solid "&[VPN provisioning_Clr]&";position:absolute;color:"&[VPN provisioning_Clr]&";'> "&[VPN provisioning]&"
    </div>
    <div style='display:inline-block;width: 100%;background-color:"&[VPN provisioning_Clr]&";text-align:center;border:1px solid;z-index:-1;filter:alpha(opacity=20);opacity:0.2;'>"&[VPN provisioning]&"
    </div>
</div>"
```

Comment: This is not email. You can't address a single user.

Comment: *There is no mail here*. I don't think you understand at all how this site works.

Comment: I have re-edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Classic UI in SharePoint Online...

Two possible issues:

- Check to see if the site has the Minimal Download Strategy enabled.
  If so disable it and test your code. MDS often is the cause for JavaScript running only once. (The page is not reloaded, only the data area.)
- The loading of the next page of the list is via a Web Service call and that may not be triggering your JavaScript. (Again, the page is not reloaded, only the data area.) You may need to intercept the paging link to insure your code is run.  (Also check to see if the "Asynchronous Load" option has been enabled. Edit the page, edit the web part, and expand the "AJAX Options" section.)

You may want to take a look at a workflow plus a Calculated column solution to add the color coding. See: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2018/01/adding-html-to-sharepoint-columns-color.html

Comment: thank you sir..will let you know once I will get into the issue again.